# Variable take value of init every time

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a menu with 3 elements, when I click an element the classes values changed to get the active element; but the problem that after a second the page got refreshed automatically and the classes get the default value and of course I got the wrong element Active.

***HTML:***

```
<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
  <a [class]="accueilClassValue" (click)="ChangeActiveMenu(1)" href="accueil">Accueil</a>
  <a [class]="proposeClassValue" (click)="ChangeActiveMenu(2)" href="propose">Proposer Un CoVoiturage</a>
  <a [class]="chercheClassValue" (click)="ChangeActiveMenu(3)" href="search">Chercher Un CoVoiturage</a>
</nav>
```

***TS:***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  menuIndex = 1;
  accueilClassValue = "nav-item nav-link active";
  proposeClassValue = "nav-item nav-link";
  chercheClassValue = "nav-item nav-link";


  ChangeActiveMenu(index : number){
    this.menuIndex = index;

    if (this.menuIndex==1){
      this.accueilClassValue = "nav-item nav-link active";
      this.proposeClassValue = "nav-item nav-link";
      this.chercheClassValue = "nav-item nav-link";
    }
    else if (this.menuIndex==2){
      this.accueilClassValue = "nav-item nav-link";
      this.proposeClassValue = "nav-item nav-link active";
      this.chercheClassValue = "nav-item nav-link";
    }
    else if (this.menuIndex==3){
      this.accueilClassValue = "nav-item nav-link";
      this.proposeClassValue = "nav-item nav-link";
      this.chercheClassValue = "nav-item nav-link active";
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use routerLink instead of href here. Remove href from the code and add routerLink to it. Angular dynamically generates its href.

Comment: Thanks Arvind !! it really works and thank you for the explanation too

Comment: Happy to help!! Please consider accepting this answer.